# python one line statement for loop with if else

Tags: python

Is it possible to write this logic in one line statement?

```
B = []
for book in books:
    if book not in B:
         B.append(book)
```

I have tried this but it's false:

```
B = [book if book not in B for book in books]
```

Is there a way to reference the variable inside itself?

Comment: Do you mean `B = set(books)`…?

Comment: yes that's it  @deceze

Comment: @deceze used to use `B = list(set(books))`

Comment: @C.LECLERC Sure, if you insist on having a `list`. If any iterable will do, keeping it as a `set` is just fine as well.

Answer (score -5):

```
B=[book for book in books if  not book in B]
```

should do the trick

Comment: I havetried this code but the books of B are duplicated ..

Comment: @pietà Because `B` is only being defined after this comprehension is done. This will actually fail with a `NameError: name 'B' is not defined`. If you still have a `B = []` defined previously you obviously circumvent that error…